# Usage of Fortran statement functions

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I read about statement functions, such as the example:

```
C(F) = 5.0*(F - 32.0)/9.0
```

Isn't this the same as:

```
C = 5.0*(F - 32.0)/9.0
```

i.e. without the function part, or maybe I'm missing something?

If they're not the same, when do I need to use a statement function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
C = 5.0*(F - 32.0)/9.0
```

is just assignment to a variable `C`, it can be anywhere and is evaluated once every time when the program flow reaches it.

```
C(F) = 5.0*(F - 32.0)/9.0
```

is a statement function, and can be evaluated any time it is in the scope by, e.g., `C(100)` which returns approximately `37.8`.

From some code

```
  xx(i) = dx*i

  f(a) = a*a

  do i = 1, nx
     x = xx(i)
     print *, f(x)
  end do
```

The `f(x)` in the print statement is evaluated with each new value of `x` and yields a new value. The value of `x` is also result of evaluation of the statement function `xx` on the previous line.

But statement functions are now (in Fortran 95) declared obsolete. Better use internal functions in any new code. E.g.,

```
program p
  implicit none
  !declarations of variables x, i, nx, dx

  do i = 1, nx
     x = xx(i)
     print *, f(x)
  end do
contains

  real function xx(i)
    integer, intent(in) :: i
    xx = dx*i
  end function

  real function f(a)
    real, intent(in) :: a
    f = a*a
  end function
end program
```

Comment: "But statement functions are now declared obsolete", this is what I need, thanks

Comment: I wonder why they are obsolete. It seems like useful language feature to have.

Comment: The declaration is confusing and introduces unnecessary variables in the scope. The internal functions are more universal. A truly useful would be modern lambda expressions and closures, but not this.