# Do these 2 lines of Fortran represent a Fortran macro?

Tags: fortran

I am converting some Fortran code to C and I don't understand what is going on here.

This code came from TOMS, Transactions on Mathematical Software, so I don't believe this is an errant line of code.

ZCOS and A have no other definitions in the file other than what I am showing here. Is this a Fortran technique for defining ZCOS as COS, and if so, what does it accomplish?

```
REAL ZCOS
ZCOS(A) = COS(A)      
C(I) = ONE / (TWO * ZCOS ( C(I) * PI / DBLE(N+N) ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a statement function, explained many times [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182512/fortran-usage-of-statement-functions). `ZCOS` is a real function and is defined in the first 2 lines.

The first line define the type of `ZCOS`.

The second line defines the function itself.

The third line could be an array access or another statement function. It cannot be decided without context.

Remark: Often, `ZCOS` is a specific functions for the `COS` generic, taking a `double complex` argument. It is a non-standard extension and your code does not use this intrinsic.

Comment: Thank you. I did numerous searches and came up blank. That is why I put the word macro in my question.