# The left-hand side has indices, but isn't declared an array

Tags: arrays, fortran

Please help me determine what the Fortran statements (part of a bigger program) below are doing. My Fortran knowledge is *lacking* and searching for info elsewhere has not helped me.

The code is as follows:

```
REAL    :: flux3, flux4, flux5, flux6
REAL    :: q_im3, q_im2, q_im1, q_i, q_ip1, q_ip2, ua, vel

flux4(q_im2, q_im1, q_i, q_ip1, ua) =                     &
       ( 7.*(q_i + q_im1) - (q_ip1 + q_im2) )/12.0
```

`flux4` is not a function since it is not declared as such in the code and if it were, it would appear on the RHS of some assignment.  What throws me are the 5 indices.  However `flux4` is simply declared as a `REAL` but is not dimensioned.  How then can it have indices?

When I compile this as a tiny Fortran program it compiles just fine.  What purpose does `flux4` serve? It looks to be an array in the assignment (5 indices) but is not declared as such.

Comment: This is a [statement function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25182512/).  Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/2103/modern-alternatives-to-historical-features/14317/statement-functions#t=201701232235144210308).

Comment: Thx francescalus - that helps immensely.  The only thing I don't get is that "ua" is in the argument list but does not show up in the right hand side because flux4() is called later on multiple times, with 5 arguments, and since "ua" doesn't appear in the (right-hand side) function definition, one would not know how the 5th argument would be used??

Comment: That just makes the function result independent of that argument (as with any other type of procedure).  That could be a mistake, or to have the interface consistent with other functions (including itself from the past).

Comment: thx.  Makes sense.

Comment: As an additional comment, a function result may in some (other) circumstances appear on the LHS of an assignment: when the function result is a data object pointer.